# ANTLR Grammar gives me upsidedown-tree

Tags: antlr

I have a grammar which parses dot notion expressions like this:
a.b.c

```
memberExpression returns [Expression value]
  : i=ID                                     { $value = ParameterExpression($i.value); }
    ('.' m=memberExpression                  { $value = MemberExpression($m.value, $i.value); }
    )*     
  ;
```

This parses expressions fine and gives me a tree structure like this:

```
MemberExpression(
   MemberExpression(
     ParameterExpression("c"),
     "b"
   )
   , "a"
)
```

But my problem is that I want a tree that looks like this:

```
MemberExpression(
   MemberExpression(
     ParameterExpression("a"),
     "b"
   )
   , "c"
)
```

for the same expression "a.b.c"

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do this by collecting all tokens in a `java.util.List` using ANTLR's convenience `+=` operator and create the desired tree using a custom method in your `@parser::members` section:

```
// grammar def ...

// options ...

@parser::members {
  private Expression customTree(List tks) {
    // `tks` is a java.util.List containing `CommonToken` objects
  }
}

// parser ...

memberExpression returns [Expression value]
  :  ids+=ID ('.' ids+=ID)* { $value = customTree($ids); }
  ;
```

Answer (score 0):

I think what you are asking for is mutually left recursive, and therefore ANTLR is not a good choice to parse it.

To elaborate, you need C at the root of the tree and therefore your rule would be:

```
rule: rule ID;
```

This rule will be uncertain whether it should match

```
a.b
```

or

```
a.b.c
```